# Can I add lentils to a baked chicken-and-vegetable stew?

Tags: baking, chicken, stews, lentils, legumes

I plan to prepare healthy lunch quickly by having everything tossed in to oven together. I have even brought an IKEA tray (with grate) for this purpose - https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/koncis-ofenform-mit-rost-edelstahl-10099053/

If I also want to bake some lentils together with it, can add some water + lentils in the same tray?

Comment: I can highly recommend 'The Roasting Tin' by Rukmini Iyer for the sort of cooking you're interested in.

Comment: Hi ishan, we work with the same rules as all other Stack Exchange sites. First, we don't take multiple questions in one. Second, out of the four separate questions you had, the first two were list questions, which would have been closed if they had been asked on their own. The fourth would have been a duplicate, search for tough meat or tough chicken and you will find a lot. So instead of closing, I left the third one only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would strongly suggest boiling the lentils first and then adding them to the bake or to the semi-finished product.**

Keep in mind that when baking at 325 F lentils may easily take [30-60 minutes](https://www.jessicagavin.com/how-to-cook-lentils/).

Adding the lentils separately, once cooked, will let you control the flavour and texture of the respective dishes as well. For example let’s say you were to bake for 60 minutes to ensure the lentils are cooked. However your other meal ends up possibly over cooked, and it could easily ruin the meal’s nutritional content and unique textures, especially for denatured protein such as chicken or pork.

Regardless of cooking via stovetop or in the oven it will be critical to know what type of lentil; different varieties can range from 30 minutes at 325 for red lentils to as much as 60 minutes or more in cook time for brown lentils.

**If you’re mixing everything in the stove it’s hard to control water content**

[Lentils absorb water quickly when cooking](https://downshiftology.com/recipes/how-to-cook-lentils/), up to 100% of their volume in water. If you’re just throwing them into a low-moisture dish in the oven they may not cook at all, and trust me, it’ll back you up if you eat uncooked lentils.